# How can I change color when any portion of SVG is hovered?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to have a SVG change color on hover when any of the area is hovered over. It's working for the "top-most" SVG but not the bottom one. The bottom SVG only registers a hover on the bottom half - is this from the bounding SVG box covering the `z-index:-1` `svg`? Removing the z-index causes the issue for the other SVG.

How can I have it so when any portion of the SVG is hovered over it will change color? I would only like the currently hovered SVG to change color, not both if either are hovered.

```css
 .wrapper {
   position: relative;
   width: 50%;
 }

 svg {
   stroke-width: 1;
   fill: lightblue;

 }

path:hover {
   fill: blue;
 }

 #svg1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }

 #svg2 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 0;
   z-index:-1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="
             M2,50
             A50,10 0 0,0 98,50
             A50,10 0 0,0 2,50
             L2,75
             A50,10,0 0,0 98,75
             L98,50             
             " style="stroke:#660000;" />
  </svg>
  <svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="
             M2,50
             A50,10 0 0,0 98,50
             A50,10 0 0,0 2,50
             L2,75
             A50,10,0 0,0 98,75
             L98,50             
             " style="stroke:#660000;" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Trying your code snippet, it does change color just not consistent.

Comment: Any idea why it's inconsistent or how to make it consistent?

Comment: The problem is that the svg's height is higher than the path's height so they end up covering each other so you are only hovering the same svg

Comment: I would use only one svg element for both shapes.  Also instead of 2 paths you can use one path and one <use> element translated in the required position.